# Django, how to fix max decimal in floatfield in annotate?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the following code:

```
annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('prezzo')*0.50/12),output_field=FloatField()
```

but in my template I have as results (for example) 145,555555555555555555555555 instead 145,55

I have added `|intcomma` but the result is the same.

How could I fix this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with [float](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/) format

```
{{ value|floatformat:2 }}
```